# How to INSERT a record or UPDATE if it already exists?

Tags: mysql, insert, insert-update

I have a table with columns `record_id` (auto inc), `sender`, `sent_time` and `status`.

In case there isn't any record of a particular sender, for example "sender1", I have to INSERT a new record otherwise I have to UPDATE the existing record which belongs to "user1".

So if there isn't any record already stored, I would execute

```
# record_id is AUTO_INCREMENT field
INSERT INTO messages (sender, sent_time, status)
VALUES (@sender, time, @status)
```

Otherwise I would execute UPDATE statement.

Anyway.. does anyone know how to combine these two statements in order to insert a new record if there isn't any record where the field sender value is "user1" otherwise update the existing record?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

MySQL supports the [insert-on-duplicate](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/insert-on-duplicate.html) syntax, f.e.:

```
INSERT INTO table (key,col1) VALUES (1,2)
  ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE col1 = 2;
```

Comment: The syntax is even more powerful than that: "ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE col1 = VALUES(col1) is a more elegant way to do what you describe (and it works on multi-row inserts). You can also use the value of col1, as in ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE col1 = col1 + 1.

Comment: why do you do col1=col1+1. What does that mean?

Comment: Stumbled across this thread... col1 = col1 +1 is an example where perhaps you have a count in your table, rather than using SELECT to get the value and add 1, it will reference the current value in the table, and perform a calculation making the SELECT statement redundant.

Answer (score 14):

If you have solid constraints on the table, then you can also use the [`REPLACE INTO`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replace.html) for that. Here's a cite from MySQL:

> *REPLACE works exactly like INSERT, except that if an old row in the table has the same value as a new row for a PRIMARY KEY or a UNIQUE  index, the old row is deleted before the new row is inserted.*

The syntax is basically the same as `INSERT INTO`, just replace `INSERT` by `REPLACE`.

```
INSERT INTO messages (sender, sent_time, status) VALUES (@sender, time, @status)
```

would then be

```
REPLACE INTO messages (sender, sent_time, status) VALUES (@sender, time, @status)
```

Note that this is a MySQL-specific command which doesn't occur in other DB's, so keep portability in mind.

Comment: Well deleting the old row will cause complications when the row is a parent of many other tables. Those with cascade delete will delete all the relationship. We really just want to do update.

Answer (score 5):

As others have mentioned, you should use "insert...on duplicate key update", sometimes referred to as an "upsert". However, in your specific case you don't want to use a static value in the update, but rather the values you pass in to the values clause of the insert statement.

Specifically, I think you want to update two columns if the row already exists:

```
1) sent_time
2) status
```

In order to do this, you would use an "upsert" statement like this (using your example):

```
INSERT INTO messages (sender, sent_time, status) 
VALUES (@sender, time, @status)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE 
  sent_time = values(sent_time),
  status = values(status);
```

Answer (score 3):

Check out ["Insert on Duplicate Key Update"](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html).

```
INSERT INTO table (a,b,c) VALUES (1,2,3)
  ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE c=c+1;

UPDATE table SET c=c+1 WHERE a=1;
```

Comment: Not true - "ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE (added in MySQL 4.1.0)"

Answer (score 1):

One options is using on duplicate update syntax

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/insert-on-duplicate.html

Other options is doing select to figure out if record exists and then doind inser/update accordingly. Mind that if you're withing transaction select will not explicitly terminate the transaction so it's safe using it.

Answer (score -1):

```
use merge statement :

merge into T1
          using T2
          on (T1.ID = T2.ID)
    when  matched
    then  update set  
                      T1.Name = T2.Name
    when  not matched
    then  insert values (T2.ID,T2.Name);
```

Comment: MySQL does not support merge statement.