# INSERT on update. Compound Key

Tags: php, mysql, insert

I have a question on [This](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/insert-on-duplicate.html) MySQL statement.

I got this from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1952922/how-to-insert-a-record-or-update-if-it-already-exists)

However, I am not sure how to structure the query when I have the table like this.

```
     TableA
     --------
     id ==> Auto Increment field
     question_id
     form_id
     member_id
     event_id
     admin_id 
     desc
     is_cand_field
     c_field_id
```

In this, `question_id, form_id, memmber_id, event_id, admin_id` can be same. `desc, is_cand_field, c_field_id` can change. When inserting, I want to check if this combination exists. If exists, I want to update the last 3 fields. If not, I want to insert a record.

Is this possible with the above referred query. Its not clear from the page.

Comment: `desc` is a bad name for a column. It will give you problems if you forget to quote it.

Comment: I just made up these names. Real names are different, though! Thanks for the comment anyways!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Add unique key on combination of these fields:

   ```
   ALTER TABLE `tablea` ADD UNIQUE INDEX `compound_key` (`question_id`, `form_id`, `member_id`, `event_id`, `admin_id`);
   ```
2. Insert values and add update section:

   ```
   INSERT INTO tablea (`question_id`, `form_id`, `member_id`, `event_id`, `admin_id`, `desc`, `is_cand_field`, `c_field_id`)
   VALUES (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 0, 1)
   ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `desc` = VALUES(`desc`), is_cand_field = VALUES(`is_cand_field`), c_field_id = VALUES(`c_field_id`)
   ```

Comment: I don't think you need `VALUES` in the `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`.

Comment: It's better than repeating values - when you have parametrized query you don't have to double bind them. Also you can insert /update multiple rows with their respective values in single query, no need for one query per row.

Comment: I was thinking there is a way to do this without even adding the compound key to the table. But anyways, this is going to be the only relevant answer

Comment: Without adding unique key you would have to query database and find if there is a record with those values, like @Tornike posted, but  that way you don't use `ON DUPLICATE KEY` statement.

Comment: @dev-null-dweller Yes, I am aware of the other route. But I thought there might be some flexibility in the statement itself to allow specifying the unique keys. Thanks anyways!

Answer (score 0):

You can add multiple rows in the `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` section.

```
INSERT INTO TableA (form_id, member_id, event_id, admin_id, desc, is_cand_field, c_field_id)
VALUES (2, 3, 4, 5, 'b', 0, 1)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE desc='a', is_cand_field=1, c_field_id=2
```

Comment: It does not check if this combination `question_id, form_id, memmber_id, event_id, admin_id` exists or not.  Or does it?

Comment: Only if that combination is a UNIQUE key in the database.