# Page count function

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, html

Every time I get a visit to my index page I need to check if a record exists already in my database, if it does, it will need to update the field 'count' if not it will add a row.

I've managed to get it to create a row on visit, but cant seem to get it to update the count if the row already exists.

```html
// Create connection
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

// Check to see if record exists
$sql = "SELECT * FROM page_tracking where name ="index.php"";
if (mysqli_query ($conn, $sql)) {
 $sql= "UPDATE page_tracking SET count=count+1 where name= "index.php")";
}

else if {
//Insert Query
$sql = "INSERT INTO page_tracking (name, count)
VALUES ('index.php', '1')"; 
}
if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
    echo "Thanks for visiting! Your visit has been recorded";
} else {
    echo "Unfortunately we were unable to record your visit: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($conn);
}
```

There's probably a really simple explanation! Issue is definitely with the code for 'check to see if record exists'

Comment: you can remove Select query and directly execute update query if it return false then you can insert vale .

Comment: Do you need the output? [How to INSERT a record or UPDATE if it already exists?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1952922/how-to-insert-a-record-or-update-if-it-already-exists)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Dont use `double quotes` around index.php use `single quotes`.
Just run update query

```
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM page_tracking where name ="index.php"";
    $result =  mysqli_query ($conn, $sql);
    $num_rows = mysqli_num_rows($result);
    if ($num_rows) {
        $sql= "UPDATE page_tracking SET count=count+1 where name= 'index.php'";

    }else{
    $sql = "INSERT INTO page_tracking (name, count) VALUES ('index.php', '1')"; 
}

if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
    echo "Thanks for visiting! Your visit has been recorded";
} else {
    echo "Unfortunately we were unable to record your visit: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($conn);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code, you never executed the query. Only created it in a string.

```
if (mysqli_query ($conn, $sql)) {
    $sql= "UPDATE page_tracking SET count=count+1 where name= "index.php")";
    # execute the query
}
```

Also, not sure why this loose `else if` without a condition:

```
else if {
    //Insert Query
```

An you may want to checkout the [`INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-on-duplicate.html) statement, which can reduce your whole code to a single query if the file name is your unique key:

```
mysqli_query ($conn, "
    INSERT INTO page_tracking (name, count)
         VALUES ('index.php', 1)
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE count=count+1
");
```

Answer (score 0):

Get the results and check whether it has records.

```
  // Check to see if record exists
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM page_tracking where name ="index.php"";
    $query = mysqli_query ($conn, $sql);

    $result=mysqli_fetch_all($query,MYSQLI_ASSOC);
    if (count($result) > 0) {
        $sql= "UPDATE page_tracking SET count=count+1 where name="index.php")";
    }

    else {
    //Insert Query
    $sql = "INSERT INTO page_tracking (name, count)
    VALUES ('index.php', '1')"; 
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this. Use single quote instead of double quote.

```
$link = mysql_connect("localhost", $mysql_user, $mysql_password);
mysql_select_db($database, $link);

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM page_tracking where name ='index.php'", $link);
$num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);

if($num_rows==1){
  //Update Query
}else{
  //Insert Query
}
```