# Insert Or Ignore with update previous row?

Tags: php, mysql

I have following table 
[image]

I am trying  if I **have new record with same email id**. I want to update previous records with that `emailId` in single query.

I don't want to update record with i have duplicate record. I am using insert ignore for that.

Any help?

Comment: no that's not possible

Comment: @RushilPachchigar In what sense is this not possible?

Comment: See the manual under INSERT

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to INSERT a record or UPDATE if it already exists?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1952922/how-to-insert-a-record-or-update-if-it-already-exists)

Answer (score -1):

make email-id as a primary key and use the following Query

```
INSERT INTO table_name
VALUES
    ('id', 'email', 'val1', 'val2') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE 'something
```

'